# djangoを始める時のコードの置き場所について。USBにコードを置くことはできますか？

Tags: python, django, windows-10, anaconda3

> コードはどこに置くの？
>   (モダンなフレームワークを使わない) 古いプレーンな PHP の経験があるなら、これまでは Web サーバのドキュメントルート下 (/var/www といった場所) にコードを配置してきたことでしょう。 Django ではそうしないでください｡ Python コードを Web サーバーのドキュメントルート下に置かないでください｡コードをドキュメントルート下に置くと、 誰かがコードを Web を介して読めるようになってしまうからです。これは安全上良くありません。
>   コードはドキュメントルートの外､例えば /home/mycode の ような場所に置きましょう。

`django`をちらほら始めてみたいなと考えています。チュートリアルドキュメントを読み進めていますと、このような文章に出会いました。おいてはいけない場所はわかるのですが、逆においてもいい場所とか、置くのに適した場所というのはありませんか？私は`Pygame`や`PySide`で今までコードを書いてきました。そして、コードはUSBメモリに入れてきました。`Anaconda`でそのUSB内にあるpyあるいはpywファイルをクリックすると、コードを実行編集保存削除などできます。どこに持って行ってもパソコンを換えてもすぐに使えるので便利です。（昔はPythonがインストールされたディレクトリ内がある場所じゃないとだめなんだと思っていましたが、だんだん融通が利くものだという事がわかってきました。
　前置きが長いかもしれませんが、`django`で`mysite`パッケージを置くときに、

> コマンドラインから、コードを置きたい場所に cd して、以下のコマンドを 実行してください。
>   $ django-admin startproject mysite

と書いてあるんですけれども、コマンドラインからUSBメモリには移れないようですね。今までと少し勝手が違うんだなと思って迷っています。初歩的なところで申し訳ありませんがどなたか教えていただけませんか？

実行環境

```
python3.6.3 django 2.02 windows10 Anaconda3
```

Comment: 回答内容に関わってくるので、想定している実行環境(OSの種類など)も記載された方がよいかと思います。恐らくWindowsでしょうが、コマンドプロンプトからリムーバルドライブに移動する事自体は可能です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windowsのコマンドプロンプトでは`cd`でドライブを移動したい場合は、`/d`オプションが必要です。

```
cd /d E:¥mysite
```

または、ドライブの移動は次のようにしてできます。

```
E:
```

Linuxと同じように使いたいのであれば、`PowerShell`の方を使うといいです。

Comment: USBに行ってdjangoが動くか確認してみます。返事はしばらくお待ちください。

Comment: USBにmysiteフォルダを作成できたうえ、インストールの成功が出来たというサイトに飛ぶことができました。ありがとうございます！